# Magento product listing page shows only 10000 products in frontend

Tags: php, magento2

I have a category which has 16k products, but in front end it is only showing 10k products every time. I have also tried this link posted by some anonymous user:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/225c498e81565fd6d6a3de670c008593

but this post is also of no use. Can any one let me know if there is any way to override a search_request.xml file (which has `<size>10000</size>` set) as I don't want to change the base file?

Comment: after wasting my 2 days i was able to figure it out. however, the above link was correct to  a extent but there's a need to  change the module version and to give sequencing in a correct way.

you can use this link to create your own module. 

http://www.credevator.com/magento2-how-to-override-the-product-list-limit-on-category-page-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a limitation of 10,000 products assigned to one category
Magento has also configuration value devoted for how much products should be displayed on Search/Advanced Search/Category page
It could be found in `CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml`

```
<size>10000</size>
```

Creating custom module to override the search_request.xml file. i have attached custom module [Download](https://github.com/hafizjee/Show-More-10k-Products-in-Frontend)

Answer (score 0):

By Default magento2 show 10,000 Products in category. if you have more than 10k products in your category then you have to change the size in vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/search_request.xml

You can't change the core file directly. so u have to override the file in your module.

**1st Method**:

Kindly check the below URL to create new module and override the xml file.

[Override the XML File](https://www.credevator.com/magento2-how-to-override-the-product-list-limit-on-category-page-in-magento-2/)

**2nd Method**:

If you have an existing module, then change the module version in module.xml and add the sequence and then override the file. (Run Upgrade Command).